# Google Hangout API to make a call

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I want to make a simple desktop icon that can be clicked to trigger a Google Hangout API call to a specific user.

I can't seem to find the right API to use or way to go about this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

i think this is not possible. the new hangouts api is only to create chat bots.
so you could create a chat bot that starts a conversation with a specific user and forwards your messages.